# Apache POI create rows or table inside cell in excel

Tags: java, apache-poi, cell, rows

I have come across need to add table or rows inside cell in excel.

I googled but did't found any thing.

Please help me know how to do it.

Comment: Question is not sufficient to make someone understand your problem... Please show us any screenshot by doing manually along with what you have tried till now...

Answer (score 0):

are you looking for this ?

```
Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
//Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
CreationHelper createHelper = wb.getCreationHelper();
Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet("new sheet");

// Create a row and put some cells in it. Rows are 0 based.
Row row = sheet.createRow((short)0);
// Create a cell and put a value in it.
Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
cell.setCellValue(1);

// Or do it on one line.
row.createCell(1).setCellValue(1.2);
row.createCell(2).setCellValue(
createHelper.createRichTextString("This is a string"));
row.createCell(3).setCellValue(true);

// Write the output to a file
FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("workbook.xls");
wb.write(fileOut);
fileOut.close();
```

Comment: No.What I want is create table inside cell.